# Inferring generic type parameter based on another generic parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Yes, sorry about the terrible title for this question, but it's hard to explain. Much simpler to show some code and ask *why does this not work as I intend?*:

```
interface Doer<U> {
    doStuff: () => U;
}

class Promiser implements Doer<Promise<string>> {
    doStuff() {
        return Promise.resolve('foo');
    }
}

export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function doYourThing<T extends Doer<U>, U>(doer: Type<T>): U {
    return new doer().doStuff();
}

const result = doYourThing(Promiser);
// type of "result" is `{}`
// I want it to be `Promise<string>`
```

An editable version of the above code [can be found here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Doer%3CU%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doStuff%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20U%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Promiser%20implements%20Doer%3CPromise%3Cstring%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doStuff()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve('foo')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Type%3CT%3E%20extends%20Function%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doYourThing%3CT%20extends%20Doer%3CU%3E%2C%20U%3E(doer%3A%20Type%3CT%3E)%3A%20U%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20doer().doStuff()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20doYourThing(Promiser)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20of%20%22result%22%20is%20%60%7B%7D%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20want%20it%20to%20be%20%60Promise%3Cstring%3E%60%0D%0A).

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I'd like TypeScript to be able to infer the return type of `doYourThing()` based on the fact that the argument is of type `Doer<U>` and the actual argument is of type `Doer<Promise<string>>`.

Is what I am attempting even possible (I'm on TypeScript 2.4.2 right now)?

If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately unification of higher-kinded typing like this doesn't work out of the box. There's a slightly more awkward "flattened" encoding of HKTs outlined in "lightweight higher kinded typing" (TypeScript examples [here](https://medium.com/@gcanti/higher-kinded-types-in-typescript-static-and-fantasy-land-d41c361d0dbe)), from which you might be able to get better inference.

Fortunately for your example, there's a simpler way to rearrange things:

```
...

function doYourThing<T>(doer: Type<Doer<T>>): T {
    return new doer().doStuff();
}

const result = doYourThing(Promiser);
// result is `Promise<string>`
```